# Convert lists into dicts and access dict fields with dot-notation

Tags: python, python-2.x

Using python 2.7 (requirement coming from other factors):

Given I have

```
x1=["John", "Doe"]
x2=["Jane", "Dan"]
x=[x1, x2]
```

I need to have some function `convert` such that `y=convert(x)`(or on an individual `x#`), and I will be able to access those values by a field-name, i.e.

```
>>y[1].name
Jane
>>y[0].surname
Doe
```

---

I've tried with `map` this way:

```
y=map(lambda person: {"name":person[0], "surname":person[1]}, x)
```

But it only works doing `y[1]["name"]`, but not `y[1].name`.

Can I get some assistance? I'm sure I'm 99% done, but I can't find the quid of it.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are having trouble with. Dictionaries *are objects*. Do you mean some other object of a user-defined type? Do you know how to create a class, then create and instance of that class?

Comment: You say you want to convert to a dict, but it looks like you don't. You want something that can be accessed with attribute syntax instead (`whatever.name`). Have you tried `NamedTuple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` becomes a list of dicts, not a list of classes.

```
>>> print(list(y))
[{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'surname': 'Dan'}]
```

Python is not Javascript; you cannot use dot-notation to access fields of dictionaries.

If this is what you wanted, you could use a NamedTuple, which creates a *class with properties*.

```
from collections import namedtuple

x1=["John", "Doe"]
x2=["Jane", "Dan"]
x=[x1, x2]

Person = namedtuple('Person', ['name', 'surname'])

y = map(lambda person: Person(name=person[0], surname=person[1]), x)
for p in y:
    print "{} {}".format(p.name, p.surname)
```

Same answer applies for Python3 when you do (and should) upgrade.

Comment: Could also do `Person(*person)`, to avoid manually indexing.

Comment: I think that's my problem, I'm thinkin JS and wanted access properties with dot notation. Thank you!

Comment: @CrazyChucky Or `lambda (name, surname): Person(name, surname)` if we want to be that explicit or just to reminisce about this lost feature once more. Or `map(Person, *zip(*x))` if we want short.

Comment: @KellyBundy Lost feature?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Wouldn't you call it that? I liked it.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was just asking what you meant. I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Ah. The [tuple parameter unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3113/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class.  This is quick and dirty, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

```py
x1=["John", "Doe"]
x2=["Jane", "Dan"]
x=[x1, x2]

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

y=[]

for p in x:
    person = Person(p[0], p[1])
    y.append(person)

print(y[0].name)
```